# Change the value of an existing onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that is pulling in via an iframe a page of html content from a pre-existing content management system, whose content I can not directly change. I want to use jquery to alter some of the links and button locations dynamically.

For links within the page I was able to change the href attr values of

```
<a href="/content.asp">more</a>
```

from content.asp to content2.asp using

```
$("a[href^='/content.asp']")
.each(function()   {       this.href = this.href.replace("content.asp",          "content2.asp");   });
```

But the page pulled in also has form buttons that contains javascript onclick functions e.g.

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add to basket" onClick="document.location='/shopping-basket.asp?mode=add&id_Product=1076';">
```

I basically want to use jquery to select any such buttons and change the shopping-basket.asp to shopping-basket2.asp

How can I select these buttons/onclick functions and change the location string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very proud of this solution, but it works....

```
var getid = /id_Product=(\d+)/;
$('input[type="button"]').each(function() {
    var onclick = String(this.onclick);
    var id = onclick.match(getid);
    if(id) {
        this.onclick = function() {
            window.location = "/shopping-basket2.asp?mode=add&id_Product=" + id[1];
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not going to work. The onclick attribute takes a function, not a string.

Comment: I could swear it worked on my first test so I edited it, but it's not. So, uhm, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue

```
$("input[onClick*='shopping-basket.asp']").each( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a unique `id` and then reference it from a javascript script with:

`document.getElementById("idOfButton").onClick`

Simply set the value to a new text string.

Comment: onclick doesn't take a text string.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought that I would update this answer as I have tried several combination in JQuery 1.4.1

1) onclick= function() - not working

```
$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).onclick = function() {
        window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com';
        return false;
    }
}
```

2)  $newclick = eval(...) not working

```
$("input").each(function() {
    $jscript = "window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com'; return false;"
    $newclick = eval("(function(){" + $jscript + "});");
    $(this).onclick = newclick;
```

}

btw. $newclick is evaluated to be undefined

3) the new answer that works in JQuery 1.4.1

```
$("input").each(function() {
     $(this).click(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
 });
```

I searched the JQuery API and there is no onclick documentation. Looks like click() is the way to go. 
Let me know if I have made any mistake(s).

Cheers

Comment: To get case 2) to work, try `$newclick = eval("myfunc=function(){"+$jscript+"}");`. The assignment of the function should force eval to return the function.

Answer (score -1):

Attributes are changed with the [.attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue) method.

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("href","content.asp");
});
```

You should be able to replace hard-coded-onClick text as well. To select those buttons, you can either grab all of them:

```
$("input.convertMe").each(function(){...});
```

Or you can add classes to the buttons you are specifically interested in:

```
<input type="button" class="convertMe"...>
```

Once you've done either of those two, you simply run through each testing their onClick attribute, and determining if you need to do any changes:

```
$("input.convertMe").each(function(){
  // Test onClick attr, and replace string.
});
```

Comment: Heh. The "Test onClick attr, and replace string" part is what he's asking for.